# jQuery script doesn't work in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i select option i need to activate buttons, it works in all browsers exclude IE10.

Select's html:

```
<select id="tenants" name="tenants" size="10" class="reportOption" onchange=""> 
<option     value="DSF-sdfdsfdsf" id="9" onclick="">DSF-sdfdsfdsf</option> 
<option value="HLQ - Harlequin North America" id="6" onclick="">HLQ - Harlequin North           America</option> 
<option value="HMB - Harlequin Mills and Boone" id="7" onclick="">HMB - Harlequin Mills and Boone</option> 
<option value="HQA - Harlequin Australia" id="8" onclick="">HQA - Harlequin Australia</option> 
<option value="KPC - Kensington" id="5" onclick="">KPC - Kensington</option> 
<option value="LDD - Libre Digital Inc." id="1" onclick="">LDD - Libre Digital Inc.    </option> 
<option value="SCH - Scholastic Inc." id="2" onclick="">SCH - Scholastic Inc.</option>          <option value="SSH - Simon and Shusterman" id="4" onclick="">SSH - Simon and Shusterman</option> 
</select>
```

Buttons html:

```
<div class="reportsButtons left_setup_buttons">
            <input type="button" id="addCtgBtn" class="button setup_btn" value="New"/>
            <input  type="button" id="editCtgBtn" class="button setup_btn disabled" disabled  value="Edit" onclick="showAddCategoryForm(this);"/>
            <input  type="button" id="delCtgBtn" class="button setup_btn disabled" disabled value="Delete" onclick="deleteCategory(this);"/>
        </div>
```

And my JS:

```
$("#categories option").click(function(){
                $("#categories option").removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');

                selectedCategoryId=$(this).attr('id');
                selectedCategoryName = $(this).attr('value');

                $('#editCtgBtn, #delCtgBtn').removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("disabled");
                $("#addCtg").hide();
            });
```

Comment: You don't `click` on `<option>` elements, you `change` a `<select>` element.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't manipulate the inputs' "disabled" *attribute*, but the *property*: `$('element').prop('disabled', false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change instead of click..

```
         //$("#categories")
         $("#tenants").change(function(){
            var selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected");
            $(this).find('option').removeClass('selected');
            selectedOption.addClass('selected');

            selectedCategoryId=selectedOption.attr('id');
            selectedCategoryName = $(this).val();

            $('#editCtgBtn, #delCtgBtn').removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("disabled");
            $("#addCtg").hide();
        });
```

Comment: The event is nativly supposed to be change for selects.. click for options probally isnt even implemented properly in IE.. IE sucks anyway.

Comment: NP - Please accept answer if it helped you @elpofigisto

Answer (score 0):

Note the name of select

Edit your code for

```
$("#tenants").change(function(){
```